# API integration with get and post URL in android

Tags: android, json, rest

```
for save the user - http://aeps.gear.host/api/Test/SaveUser
```

INPUT

```
{

"Name": "sample",

"EmailId": "sample@gmail.com",

"MobileNo": "9876543210",

"Gender": "MALE",

"Latitude": "99.99",

"Longitude": "99.99",

"Birthdate": "05-03-2017"

}
```

OUTPUT

```
{

"$id": "1",

"Status": true,

"Data": "[{}]",

"Message": "Details saved successfully"

}
```

for get user

2) http://aeps.gear.host/api/Test/GetDetails

INPUT

```
{

"RegistrationId": "0"

}
```

OUTPUT

```
{

"$id": "1",

"Status": true,

"Data": [

{

"$id": "2",

"RegistrationId": 1,

"Name": "sample string 1",

"EmailId": "sample string 2",

"MobileNo": "sample string 3",

"Gender": "sample string 4",

"Latitude": "sample string 6",

"Longitude": "01-01-1900",

"Birthdate": "sample string 5"

}

],

"Message": "List generated successfully"

}
```

I want to Register the user details in registration screen and show  all registered users in view user screen in android. I have a URL for get and post both with json response.

I want the user to register with name, mail , number and want to show in a simple list in next screen

Comment: for UI please refer

Comment: what is the problem exactely?

Comment: add the code you wrote so far

Comment: i dont know how to register user with rest client in android, i have three fields in xml.. name, numb, email . I want to register the new user and show the user list

Comment: http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/ this link will help me ???

Comment: i just want suggestions

Comment: @VivekMishra I recommend you to read about Retrofit.

Comment: ok i will try with retrofit and i will update here whenever i will stuck